# OnePlus 6T Android Emulator Screen Configuration Hardware Profile

Tags: android-emulator, oneplusx

Has anyone been able to properly setup OnePlust 6T android emulator with regards to the screen profile?

I set it up according to the official specs, 6.41" & 2340 x 1080:

[image]

But the emulator doesn't reflect the screen of the actual device; see below:

[image: Device Screenshot]

[image: Emulator Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

After some trial & error, it seems that the emulator's resolution of 2643 x 1220 reflects the actual device.